# Getting 405 Method Not Allowed when using HTTP

Tags: http, .net-6.0, http-status-code-405

I have a .NET 6 Core Web API which contains several endpoints, now while calling POST endpoints of my API using https URL everything works fine, if I simply change URL to http, then I am getting 405 method now allowed in response.

I am aware that 405 comes when we do not call using correct Http Verb, but here I am getting error in case of HTTP request. Does any one has any information about same?